# Persist recently used fonts in PowerPoint after closing

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

PowerPoint's recently used fonts list always clears after closing PowerPoint. This is unlike the behavior in Microsoft Word, which persists the recently used fonts list. How can I change PowerPoint's behavior to act like Word here, so that it remembers the recently used fonts and shows them again the next time it starts?

This is the same issue as https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-power-point-2010-do-not-remember-recent-fonts/4c9cc38b-d5e6-454c-be51-860625ec2317

I'm using Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's by design. In PowerPoint, the Recent Used Fonts list disappears after you close the program, unlike Word.

I can't find any reference online to any workaround for PowerPoint.You can post a suggestion at the [PowerPoint User Voice forum](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application) requesting a method to turn this on. Microsoft uses these suggestions to prioritize their programming.